# Updating Version

Tags: air, aptana

I created a new air project in aptana but launching it gets me

```
This application requires a version of the Adobe Integrated Runtime (AIR) which is no longer supported. Please contact the application author for an updated version.
```

How does one go about updating the application for a newer version of air?  I suspect it is related to

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5">
```

in the application.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed the AIR 1.0 runtime, mostly sometime before Frebruary 2009. AIR 1.5 was launched on around the last week of February. The runtime installer does check for updates. You will need the updated runtime.

There should be a link where it tells you to update the application (when you launch your application). Just click on it and install the new version of the runtime. In case you missed it -- [here](http://get.adobe.com/air/)'s the link.

Read more about AIR 1.5 [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/rchristensen_lpolanco_air_1.5.html).

If I missed the real question -- let me know!